# Personalizar a aparência do widget dialog do jquery-ui

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Eu estou tentando alterar a aparência do widget 'dialog' do jquery-ui, e até agora eu tenho o seguinte código css para isso:

```
.ui-dialog {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1050;
  display: none;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  outline: 0;
}
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar {
  min-height: 16.42857143px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
}
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
  margin-top: -2px;
}
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-radius: 6px;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
          box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane {
    text-align: left;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
    background-image: none;
    margin-top: .5em;
    padding: .3em 1em .5em .4em;
}
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset {
    float: right;
}
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane button {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1040;
  background-color: #000;
}
.ui-dialog .ui-resizable-se {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    right: -5px;
    bottom: -5px;
    background-position: 16px 16px;
}
```

O que eu consegui até agora foi isso:

[image]

Duas coisas faltam para eu conseguir o que eu quero:

1) alterar o  estilo do botão fechar (eu preciso de um fundo transparente com um X dentro dele).

2) tirar as barras de rolagem que envolvem o widget (eu quero que as barras de rolagem fiquem dentro do widget, e somente quando o conteúdo for maior do que a janela).

Alguém sabe com conseguir isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que precisa alterar é:

- `.ui-dialog`, o envólucro do dialog:

Remover o overflow, ou seja:

```
overflow: none;
/* remover isto
overflow: auto;
overflow-y: scroll;
*/
```

- `.ui-dialog-content`, o conteudo

Acrescentar altura máxima e dar OK para o scroll vertical:

```
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
```

- `close`, o botão de fechar

Aqui poderia usar `background: none;` para deixar o fundo sem cor.

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/RzGD7/)